# Do a pair of orthogonal directions with slopes equal to zero imply $\nabla f = 0$?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

The definition given on wikipedia for a saddle point is

> is a point on the surface of the graph of a function where the slopes (derivatives) in orthogonal directions are both zero (a critical point), but which is not a local extremum of the function.

Looking at their picture (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point#/media/File:Saddle_point.svg) it's clear that $f_x(0,0) = 0$ and $f_y(0,0)=0$ .... just from taking a look. What isn't as clear is that $D_u f(0,0) = 0$ and that $D_v f(0,0)=0$ whenever $u\perp v$ (for unit $u$ and $v$). However if I turn the graph so that $\langle 1,0\rangle \mapsto u$ and $\langle 0,1\rangle \mapsto v$ then I would have $D_u f(0,0) = 0$ and that $D_v f(0,0)=0$ but then I don't see why $f_x(0,0)=0$ and $f_y(0,0)=0$ in that coordinate system.

Put another way.....  Is it true that $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)=0$ if and only if $D_u f(x_0,y_0)= D_v f(x_0,y_0)=0$ for some (and hence any) pair of unit vectors $u,v$ such that $u\perp v$?

If this is true then in the boxed sentence above I could write instead "a point where $\nabla f=0$ but which ..."

Answer (score 1):

Remember than having an extrema of a differentiable function $f : \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}$ at a point $p$ implies $\nabla_p f  = 0$. The converse however is not true, and so even if your question can be answered affirmatively, this says nothing about the former.

Now, as for your question, the answer is yes if $f$ is differentiable and $k = 2$ for the following reason: since $v \perp w$, the set $\{v,w\}$ is linearly independent and therefore a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since $f$ is differentiable, we have that for any point $p$ the directional derivative with direction $u$ is

$$
f_u(p) = \langle\nabla_p f, u \rangle \tag{1}
$$

Now, if $x$ is any vector, there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $x =av+bw$ and thus,

$$
f_u(p) = \langle\nabla_p f, u \rangle = \langle\nabla_p f, av+bw \rangle = a\langle\nabla_p f,v\rangle+b\langle \nabla_p f, w \rangle = 0.
$$

In particular, the partial derivatives are zero, by taking $u = e_j$ with $1≤j≤2$. The other direction comes directly from $(1)$.

If $k>2$, the map

$$
f(x_1, \dots, x_k) =  x_k
$$

has nonzero gradient but the partial derivatives $f_1$ and $f_2$ (which in particular are directional) are zero and $e_1 \perp e_2$.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly....  this is true in one direction always but iff is only true when $k=2$?

Comment: Stronger question: Is "iff" true if and only if $k=2$??  Is there a counter-example in every dimension $k>2$?

Comment: I will have to think about that :P But yes, the 'easy' direction holds always.

Comment: I've added an additional comment.

Comment: You wrote $k>1$ not $k>2$ and I don't know what $x_k$ means in this context?

Comment: My bad, I'm on my phone at the moment. I'll fix it asap.

Comment: $\langle \nabla_ p f, ab+ bw\rangle $ or $\langle \nabla_p f, av+ bw\rangle $?

Comment: The latter, as you can see from $x = av + bw$ and the term that follows the posterior equals sign. I apologize for the amount of typos.

Comment: The intended generalization of the question should be "If a collection of mutually orthogonal $\{u_1,\ldots, u_k\}$ vectors is such that $D_{u_j} f(x_1,\ldots,x_k) = 0$ for every $j$ is it true also that $D_{e_j} f(x_1,\ldots, x_k) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}$ for every $j$?"

Also I'm not sure what $\nabla_p f$ means or $\langle \nabla_p f,v\rangle$ means but I guess it is what I'm writing as $D_v f(p)$ (the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $v$ at $p$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84109/discussion-between-guido-a-and-clclstdnt).